# How to sort s3cmd ls output by date?

Tags: awk, ls, sort, amazon-s3

I want to sort directories in an s3 storage by the date embedded in their name.

When I run

```
s3cmd ls s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/ | awk '{print $2}'
```

it lists the directories like

```
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/01_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/02_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/03_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/04_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/05_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/06_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/07_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/08_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/09_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/10_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/11_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/12_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/13_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/14_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/15_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/30_Mar_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/31_Mar_2020/
```

I want these to display in date wise order so that it looks something like this

```
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/30_Mar_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/31_Mar_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/01_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/02_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/03_Apr_2020/
....
....
```

I tried sorting with column and *-M* (for month) flag, but it isn't working.

My goal is deleting directories older than *n* days, but since [s3cmd](https://s3tools.org/s3cmd) ls doesn't return the creation/modified date of directories, I have to do it the hard way.

How may I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
... |
awk -F'[/_]' '{printf "%04d%02d%02d %s\n", $(NF-1), index("  JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$(NF-2))/3, $(NF-3), $0}' |
sort |
sed 's/[0-9]* //'
```

Notice that there are **2** spaces in `"  Jan..."`; that's not a bug: indexes in awk start from 1, not from 0 as in other languages.

Comment: This is simply amazing, any idea how can I exclude bottom `-n` directories where n is the no. count I want to retain.

for ex: I want to keep last 7 days, so it will just remove bottom 7 and then give me the result

Comment: Use `.. | tail -n7` too keep just the last 7, or `.. | head -n -7` to keep all but the last 7.

Comment: That was very helpful. I am marking this as the accepted answer. just one request can you please explain your answer a little bit so that novices like us looking for the same issue can understand it more?

Comment: @PankajJha where should I start from? What is giving you trouble? The awk thing just prepends a `YYYYMMDD` (numeric year, month and day) to each line (which sorts the same numerically and lexicographically).

Comment: Got it now, Thanks

Comment: `+1` but `index("  JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$(NF-2))/3` is more commonly written `(index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$(NF-2))+2)/3` and `cut` is more commonly used than `sed` to remove the appended string after sorting and `\t` is then more commonly used than `" "` as the separator added by `awk` since that's `cut`s default separator. So it'd be: `awk -F'[/_]' '{printf "%04d%02d%02d\t%s\n", $(NF-1), (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$(NF-2))+2)/3, $(NF-3), $0}' | sort | cut -f2-`.

Answer (score 2):

A GNU `awk` alternative with use of `date`

```
awk -F'[/_]' '{
    D=$(NF-3)"-"$(NF-2)"-"$(NF-1);
    "date +%Y-%m-%d -d "D|getline nd;
    print nd, $0
}' file1 | sort | cut -d" " -f 2
```

**Walkthrough**

Split out `$0` your fields on `/` or `_`

```
awk -F'[/_]' '{
```

Recompose them as a valid date

```
    D=$(NF-3)"-"$(NF-2)"-"$(NF-1);
```

Use the shell `date` function to convert the month from text to a number and grab it back by piping through `awk`'s `getline` into a new variable

```
    "date +%Y-%m-%d -d "D|getline nd;
```

Nothing new here

```
    print nd, $0
}' file1 | sort | cut -d" " -f 2
```

Output

```
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/30_Mar_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/31_Mar_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/01_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/02_Apr_2020/
s3://xyz/private/backups/mails/daily/03_Apr_2020/
```

**Alternative** slightly leaner using `gensub`

```
awk -F'/' '{
    "date +%Y%m%d -d "gensub("_","-","g",$(NF-1))|getline nd;
    print nd, $0
}' file1 | sort | cut -d" " -f2
```

Comment: That would be orders of magnitude slower than just manipulating the text as @mosvy is doing and if you're using GNU tools then GNU awk has built in time functions so you don't need to spawn a shell and call `date` for every input line. Also your `cut` should be `-f2-`, not just `-f2`, in case any of the input file names contain blanks. It also introduces the possibility of a getline failure going undetected and silently messing up the output by duplicating the value from the previous successful call, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for how to call getline to guard against that.

Comment: I couldn't spot the `awk` time function that would do the conversion but am no guru there. Assistance?

Comment: It's looks kinda silly since you don't need to call a date function to do this at all but `awk 'BEGIN{split("01_Apr_2020",t,/_/); print strftime("%Y%m%d",mktime(t[3]" "(index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",t[2])+2)/3" "t[1]" 0 0 0"))}'` would output `20200401`. There's also a `strptime()` library recently become available for gawk (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.awk/Ft6_h7NEIaE/tmyxd94hEAAJ) but you've got do download and compile stuff to use it so I doubt it'll ever actually be used.

Comment: TBH i was just looking for any way not to type in "janfeb..." and then `tolower()` if you want to avoid case issues etc. on one liners. Seems there is nothing to be had off the shelf ... not like it's hard to roll up a function to throw in the library for own use.

Comment: If you're going to use `date | getline` though then you really need to write `D=$(NF-3)"-"$(NF-2)"-"$(NF-1); cmd="date +%Y-%m-%d -d "D; nd="N/A"; if ( (cmd |getline line) > 0 ) nd=line; close(cmd)` so it's not briefer than writing `nd=sprintf(%04d%02d%02d",$(NF-1), (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDev",$(NF-2))+2)/3, $(NF-3))` and it's vastly slower than it and it requires GNU date.

Comment: That did get me wondering though if there's a way to generate a list of month numbers so you don't have to type them and best I could come up with was `locale mon` but then you still need to trim each month name to 3 chars so at the end of the day it's easier just to type them.

Comment: I wasted my time the same way ;).....Anyway I did a time comparison over 1,000 iterations and the `date` call is about 1 order of (10x) magnitude slower than @mosvy, So then I just rolled my own function and threw it in a library script. No appreciable difference between doing this and in line code. At least I wont  be needing to type this again for my own use,